# django-resized // When upload png file, it's extension changed to .apng

Tags: django

I am using the django-resized package to resize the image.

When I upload a PNG file using this package, the extension is changed to apng.
I don't want this extension to change..

Other image files are normally uploaded.

What should I fix it?

Background
- django==2.1.5
- django-resized==0.3.9

When use Django's default model.ImageField, the extension of png does not change.

```py
# models.py

def upload_to(instance, filename):
    return 'vip/{username}/{filename}'.format(
        username=instance.whose.whose.username, filename=filename)

class VipIndex(models.Model):
    whose = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vipindex')
    main_big_image = ResizedImageField(crop=['middle', 'center'], size=[500, 300], quality=50, blank=True, upload_to=upload_to)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']

# forms.py

class VipMainForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = VipIndex
        fields = (
            'main_big_image',
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(VipMainForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['main_big_image'].widget.attrs = {'autocomplete': 'off', 'class': 'form-control'}


# views.py

@login_required
def profile_2(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_main = VipMainForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form_main.is_valid():
            nav = form_main.save(commit=False)
            nav.whose = request.user.profiles
            nav.save()
            return redirect('profile_2')

    else:
        form_main = VipMainForm()

    return render(request, 'accounts/profile_2.html', {
        'form_main':form_main,
    })
```

Are there specific settings to keep the extension of the png file?

Comment: Are you sure you are not actually uploading an `apng` file accidentally renamed as `png`?

Comment: Every PNG files are changed to apng...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to `settings.py`

`DJANGORESIZED_DEFAULT_FORMAT_EXTENSIONS = {'PNG': ".png"}`

and it will override saving the file as .apng

Comment: Hey just a note from the year 2022, this has solved a headache for me. Thanks, @rugy.